# How will I revive my peppermint plant

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, herbs, mint

Please help. My plants look like this today.  Yesterday it's healthy

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your mint has suffered a drought. Likely the top (stems and leaves) will not recover but we might be able to save the root and put your plant back in production. As the pot soil fills with roots, which mints tend to do quite quickly, the faster it will run out of moisture on a warm day.

So one process would be to clip off all the dry top growth and set it on one side to become completely dry, then you can crumble the leaves into a paper container and use the powder for tea, cooking and so on. Make sure the leaves are only mint, no strange weeds and so on, you get the idea. Compost the stems.

Now pull the root ball out of the pot and break it up to release the roots from the soil. As soon as you can dump the bare root into a pail of water and leave it for several hours to rehydrate as much as possible. Then pull out the root mass and look for the thick rhizomes - these will be the last part of the plant to dry out. Clip off all the roots to leave just the rhizomes, and cut these into short pieces. Take fresh soil and plant a few of the rhizome pieces in small pots. If they did not dry out much they should spring back to life with new shoots within a few days. Move the best ones into your old pot and you are back in mint production business.